# How to generate random particles without overlapping at the middle of the screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a many particles which will behave like a galaxy.
These particles positions will generate randomly.

Also I am using three js

The thing is that the posArray generator method is generating too many items at the center of the screen.

Here is the code

```
const particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.05,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  transparent: true,

});

const particlesGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const particlesCount = 30;

const posArray = new Float32Array(particlesCount * 3);

for (let i = 0; i < particlesCount; i++) {
  posArray[i] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * (Math.random() * 5);
}
```

Here is what happening
As you can see in the pic there is always some blocks at the middle of the canvas

[image]

Comment: `(Math.random() - 0.5) * (Math.random() * 5)` has the tendency to produce more numbers closer to zero, yes. As in, it's not uniform over [-2.5, 2.5]. Did you perhaps intend just `(Math.random() - 0.5) * 5`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte `(Math.random() - 0.5) * 5` still generating many items at the middle.
Is there anyway to just remove all the items from let say between `-0.5 and 0.5`

Comment: Sure, but that would be a dirty fix. I guess you use perspective projection, and not orthogonal? That would explain, why you are still visually getting too many in the center.